# What is used to seal around glass in fireplace doors?

Tags: insulation, fireplace

The glass in my fireplace doors have felt-like strips layered in between the glass and the metal framing of the doors. I recently had to have a piece of glass replaced and they lost the strips. Now when the air conditioner unit is running it pulls air in from chimney causing the house to smell like smoke.

What is the material used to seal the glass so I can correct this problem?

Comment: take pictures, measurements and jot down any model information, then head to a fireplace dealer.

Answer (score 3):

The usual material is fiberglass rope or woven fiberglass tape.

For sealing glass, the rope fits in a groove, the tape is used between a flat surface and the glass with additional pieces under the clips to cushion their grip on the window glass.

The dark stuff is impregnated with graphite to prevent it sticking to the opposite surface (door seal).

Rutland is one brand with a broad selection of sizes and types.

Answer (score 2):

During the months where air conditioning is in use you should really consider closing the damper in your chimney to reduce air intake from that source. Even with a seal from the glass of the the door to the door frame there are few fireplace door/screen units that I've found that offer a a great deal of "air tightness".

Comment: True enough, but dampers aren't exactly air tight either in my experience. Still, one should throw every bit of restriction they can into the ingress path for best results.

Comment: the damper is closed. do you know what is used in the glass