# What can I seal the top of my fireplace doors with?

Tags: fireplace, sealing, sealant

I have a wood burning fireplace with glass doors.  The top outer rim of the doors have quite a gap, allowing a decent draft and also smoke to escape when first starting a fire (which is worsened by a drafty chimney).

[image]

[image]

You can see the gap in the second photo is quite large, and leads straight into the fireplace.  Is there a way to seal this to prevent the draft and smoke from escaping? I don't think is gets particularly hot in this spot when there is a fire burning since this sticks out from where the fire actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stove rope, or fireplace seal.
Self-adhesive or with heat-resistant glue.
Many thicknesses & lengths & usually black, grey or white colour.

[Example Amazon search](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fireplace-Oven-Sealings/b?ie=UTF8&node=1938336031)

You can get fire-resistant silicate sealants that can be used like a silicone bath sealant with a gun, but reviews are mixed.

Comment: I did see [this similar post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/what-is-used-to-seal-around-glass-in-fireplace-doors), but I thought this was for in between the glass panes of the doors.  Perhaps I was mistaken!

Comment: If you look at the link, you'll see different types for different purposes - flat tape for doors, circular-section rope for larger gaps.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [Quickrete Fireplace Mortar](https://www.quikrete.com/productlines/fireplacemortar.asp)

> Withstands temperatures of 2000˚F (1093˚C)

[image]